Factorio Perfect Ratio for filling a container with the maximum possible items while maintaing a set ratio
I struggle solving an issue that I feel should be very trivial. Sadly I'm bad at math and failed to find a solution or similar problem being solved that I could apply. Probably because I don't know how to correctly label and thus search for this problem.
I encountered this problem in the game Factorio, but you certainly do not need any knowledge of the game to understand the issue. Those familiar with Factorio will simply have an easier time understanding the names of the variables used, but those are irrelevant for the underlying problem.
What I already attempted, plus some of the input variables:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EwOBmZYF1eSSX8LrJ8TwTYbgWDyvT8MX1w-v8cyd4Os/edit?gid=0#gid=0
The problem in text form:
In Factorio, there's containers that can hold various numbers of item stacks, e.g. a maximum of 500 as in this case (See cell A21).
Now, I want to fill this container with items that I need for the next process, but I want to use the available space as efficiently as possible, so fill it up with multiples of my ratio as much as I can without ruining the exact ratio of items I need. It is preferable to have some empty slots than to have an imperfect ratio that would require buffering or clean-up of superfluous items at the start of the next process.
Each line from 3-15 contains one of the needed items. Column B tells how many items are needed for a single process, so it defines the ratio of necessary items.
The thing that throws me off is that in Factorio there are some additional rules to consider:

Every item type has a different stack size, so every cargo slot can be filled with a stack of items of the maximum size listed in Column C. So a single slot can hold 1-10 Barrels or 1-200 Red Techs.
You also cannot mix different items into a single slot. So if a slot is occupied by a single Red Tech item, nothing else except more Red Tech items can use it (up to the stack size limit of 200).
At the same time, a slot does not have to be filled completely, so using less than the maximum is permissible.
Using fractions of an item, however, is not possible. Items can only ever divided into a single full item as the smallest unit.

My approach now was to calculate how much of a slot each item type would utilize (column D). Then, by simply dividing this number with the number of slots, I get the value of how many multiples of my ratio I can fill the container with in D22, which would be the proper result (multiplier of column B to use to fill the container perfectly). But only if I disregard the "cannot mix items in a single slot" rule as well as the "cannot have item fractions". If I were to use this value for the following calculation columns E-G, I would get 500 slots exactly in E17. However, I obviously also cannot have fractions of an item in a slot, and I can't mix them, so this is useless.
Column F calculates the actual number of items that I can transport, these are the actual desired results I need to know.
Column G just shows me how many slots are blocked/in use by simply rounding up the actual slots used in E, because effectively, even when a slot is occupied by even a single item, it still is fully reserved and can't be used by any other item. If I were to use the "perfect" fractional multiplier in D22, the total in G17 would end up as 503 (while E17 would be the perfect 500), so the container would in fact be overfilled.
The number 1080 in D23 is the correct multiplier result, which I only managed to find out by sheer trial & error and comparing when G17 would approximate the A21 slot limit. This multiplier leads to 6 empty slots, but this is acceptable. Using the next larger whole multiplier of 1081 leads to 501 slots being required, as almost every item would then require a new slot to start filling.
The multiplier itself could actually in theory be fractional, but only if the resulting item counts in column F end up being integers / whole numbers.
I feel like there should be a perfectly logical and simple-ish way to calculate the "magic number" 1080 and thus column E-G dynamically given different ratios and container slot limits, but for some reason it eludes me utterly. I'm also fairly certain I'm far from the first with this kind of issue, it seems a fairly common optimization issue.
I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to approach a solution, and bonus points for telling what  this type of problem is commonly known as and called.

Suppose there were a dynamic/automatic way to calculate a number that was close to the magic number $1080$ (say $1050$) and fufilled the other requirements such as perfect ratio; would you be satisfied with that? (Also—gotta get these spreadsheets working before Factorio 2 comes out—!)

I'll take anything I can get. I might be bad at math, but I'm curious and would love to know what approaches exist for problems I encounter in Real Life. And Factorio is real enough for me. ;)

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming (MILP) as follows.  Let $b_i$ and $c_i$ be the values in columns B and C.  Let nonnegative variable $m$ be the magic number, and introduce nonnegative integer variables $f_i$ and $g_i$ to represent the values in columns F and G.  The problem is to maximize $m$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
f_i &= b_i m &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1 \\
f_i &\le c_i g_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_i g_i &\le 500 \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} forces the number of items for output $i$ to be the magic number times $b_i$.  Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the stack size for output $i$.  Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the slot limit.  The maximum value of $m$ indeed turns out to be $1080$.

Super interesting, never heard of MILP before. I'm honestly surprised the problem is apparently not as simple as I expected it to be, then. Having now looked at MILP a bit, this really seems to be more of a true programming, even iterative approach. I do have an IT background, so this is easy to implement, but didn't expect it to be necessary. Thanks for the very succinct explanation!

It is not necessary to use a MILP solver, but this is a formal way to express the problem.  An alternative approach for cases like this, where the objective function is a single variable, is to do a bisection search on a bounded interval.  You know that $m\in[0,1098.9]$, and for each choice of $m$ in the search, you just need to check whether $\sum_i \lceil b_i m/c_i \rceil \le 500$.  If so, you have a feasible $m$ and can restrict the search to the right half of the interval.  If not, you can restrict the search to the left half of the interval.  Repeat until the interval is short enough.

Because you want $b_i m$ to be integer, $m$ must be a multiple of $5$, so your interval is actually a finite set: $m\in{0,5,\dots,1095}$.

RobPratt's answer is mathematically optimal. Here's a different approach that is more spreadsheet-friendly.
Let $c_i$ denote the entry in row $i$, column $C$, and similarly for other columns. The number of copies of the item in row $i$ used by a number $m$ of multiples of the base recipe is $mb_i$. The number of stacks needed to store those items is $\lceil \frac{mb_i}{c_i} \rceil$, where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling function—the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. We need the total number of stacks to be at most $500$, leading to the inequality
$$
\sum_{i=3}^{15} \biggl\lceil \frac{mb_i}{c_i} \biggr\rceil \le 500.
$$
This is difficult to exactly solve algebraically. However, for a close approximation, we can use the fact that $\lceil x\rceil < x+1$. Therefore any solution to the modified inequality
$$
\sum_{i=3}^{15} \biggl( \frac{mb_i}{c_i} +1  \biggr) \le 500
$$
will also be a solution to the original inequality. The modified inequality is the same as
$$
m \le \frac{500-13}{\sum_{i=3}^{15} \frac{b_i}{c_i}};
$$
and since $m$ must be an integer, this method leads to the valid solution
$$
m = \biggl\lfloor \frac{500-13}{\sum_{i=3}^{15} \frac{b_i}{c_i}} \biggr\rfloor
$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function or greatest-integer function—the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.
I've made a copy of the OP's spreadsheet with this formula implemented in cell I23; the calculation gives a magic number of $1070$ which is off by less than 1%.
(There might be a way to get the exact magic number in a more spreadsheet-y way using Goal Seek or some iterative calculation.)

Thank you for taking the time for providing this solution. While RobPratt's answer is understandably succinct, I did struggle finding a usable implementation of it, and after a couple hours came to realize that it indeed would require either programming/scripting or an external addon to do the iterations. Your solution is easy to understand and implement, and even more importantly, this approach would even be possible to implement using Factorio's ingame circuit combinators without being prohibitively complex and expensive to compute. It also helped me learn some some more maths today! :)
